# Tell me the Lunar Phase!

Tags: code-golf, image-processing

### Challenge

Given an image of the Moon as input, output the phase of the Moon.

### Phases of the Moon

Your program will be supplied one of these images in png format and you must output the phase exactly as given:

```
new moon
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/9b7f749f38dc0c9111915e4ffdd65991)

[image]

```
waxing crescent
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/bef0e11df0f341fd898a3374f3359e9a)

[image]

```
first quarter
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/6eb33f2bd86edacc48b2691b478d8d57)

[image]

```
waxing gibbous
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/04a900f675a7f2f6a1b55c3eb6a4802d)

[image]

```
full moon
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/306e2fb0ed1193cd2ec3c89f1f60a46b)

[image]

```
waning gibbous
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/132ae63f6af2484bdd6972c63db2b5bc)

[image]

```
third quarter
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/ed0f4874c88c0c601a621860a2764dc4)

[image]

```
waning crescent
```

[hexdump](https://gist.github.com/beta-decay/8d3b14d4ac2ad86b6ed9bc45196959ed)

[image]

### Input

The input will be the path to a 240 px by 240 px png file and will be the one of the images above.

The image bytes are guaranteed to be the same.

### Winning

Shortest code wins

Comment: As a bonus, check out this cool gif: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Lunar_libration_with_phase_Oct_2007_450px.gif

Answer (score 9):

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), 145 bytes

```javascript
p=>'third/waning/first/full/waxing/new'.split`/`[(s=require('fs').statSync(p).size)%418%6]+' '+'quarter/crescent/gibbous/moon'.split`/`[s%12%9%4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BTsMwEETvfMVKKLKjmLhp3KQVSm9wRuKCVFWqm24ao2CnXocCPx/SqgeY09Nodmfe9aem2ps@PFh3wLGpxr5as9Aaf5BnbY09ysZ4CrIZum5yvi6OxTNLqe9M2MndhlPl8TQYj5w1xOKUgg6v37bm/cTmB@NIZcuo2CYMWMJOg/YBvaw9Uo02yKPZ791A8sM5@@ctRdk8WkVqOz5ucrXIBBQqnwlYZEoJKGflhefL/MJFKUCtymLK5Hm5vUsb55903XJOAkwM1Rr4/41nbwI@mw6vQ9m1WwB7Y6nHHnXgFMcCamfJdZh27sjZS6sJ4Z5BAkZAczuKJ42/) (generates dummy files with the same sizes)

#### How?

We just look at the size of the file and convert it to indices in two lookup tables.

First part:

```
 phase | file size | mod 418 | mod 6 | mapped to
-------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------
   0   |    3451   |    107  |    5  | new
   1   |    6430   |    160  |    4  | waxing
   2   |    5144   |    128  |    2  | first
   3   |    7070   |    382  |    4  | waxing
   4   |    5283   |    267  |    3  | full
   5   |    7067   |    379  |    1  | waning
   6   |    4976   |    378  |    0  | third
   7   |    6337   |     67  |    1  | waning
```

Second part:

```
 phase | file size | mod 12 |  mod 9 |  mod 4 | mapped to
-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------
   0   |    3451   |     7  |     7  |    3   | moon
   1   |    6430   |    10  |     1  |    1   | crescent
   2   |    5144   |     8  |     8  |    0   | quarter
   3   |    7070   |     2  |     2  |    2   | gibbous
   4   |    5283   |     3  |     3  |    3   | moon
   5   |    7067   |    11  |     2  |    2   | gibbous
   6   |    4976   |     8  |     8  |    0   | quarter
   7   |    6337   |     1  |     1  |    1   | crescent
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>223</s> 222 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to OMᗺ</sup>

```python
lambda p:'new moonzzfull moonzzfirst quarterzzwaxing crescentzzwaning gibbouszzwaxing gibbouszthird quarterzwaning crescent'.split('z')[sum(n*Image.open(p).getpixel((n*48,99))[2]for n in[1,2,3,4])%13]
from PIL import Image
```

`getpixel((x,y))` - will return the RGBA pixel at `x,y`
`getpixel((n*48,99))[2]for n in[1,2,3,4]` - will return the blue channel of the middle line, where `n*48 ... for n in 1,2,3,4` will be 4 points where the sunlight may cover
`n*getpixel(...)` - will generate a different value for each column
`sum(...)%13` - these values are added together and `%13` is used to get an unique value to each phase, that will be used as index for the phase list
The pixels are approximately inside the red circles:
[image: moon picture with pixels highlighted]

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, 131 bytes

```
->f{f=open(f,'rb').read;%w[first third waxing new full waning][f[699].ord%7]+' '+%w[x moon gibbous quarter crescent][f[998].ord%5]}
```

Byte offsets found by brute force -- taking the 699th byte of the file modulo 7, for instance, gives an index into the first lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>196</s> 165 bytes

```bash
lambda f:'first quarter|new moon|waning crescent|waxing gibbous|third quarter|full moon|waxing crescent|waning gibbous'.split('|')[sum(map(ord,open(f).read()))%41%9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jXtpdxZF1/V3fkUpKAGlqK65EUVBRFBxQkGcqKkBZQxBRvnr97t3dXUS/PCsl7WMCeQ6XXWGffYZOqcnd/5X0p54LZ4/r@LUrvhE3L2fbjf56MHtI0f4L5@I8rDi5xfi7NmL337xv3vpfq5JLGeOL3d3n@yJx0/T7l7bff2gPRP3Hz588PpZenD3wW1RdtuT0h7s4efn/Pn23ZwfPn3yeu/O3d26/6nl6b1728ee/@djDw597Lh88uje3b2d46@Pn/j1ydP7O/fTo52Hu/XDh4/ag53lhNxtqe6cOHHiPTu9N//@v0e7dx/s7dzeOb5/m@MnThzB@Y8cedJw0bvi@JPTf9w7ffvje6ePbzc8cuTRi707Dx/o7S/@p8afMyLOTgnbbBCqqiSmhC/8F36pws42CmudFkJ@d/WSHH8uf/n5D0dWCRNkjN9f1OHvotLbj3kSJoQGGW/9CW@GDA0Zxant495rYTNOZC1@XJaDL0kNGfmrS58PKUOGgQzYL4jZbIc3ys6QYSfhbIhiLlBQrSFv51CXP//s2nN882rIsJAxKxeEd1MVJSyTWEJcRHMJJ4o5C9eUF5ObLWRcb@MEX8o/Ds7heJdcksBnvAhRG/zos7AaR1CzcSKFrES1buI5br7//Kj8@/xz6SDi@yHDU6fFGaofRzZTFFNNOIxWi/Ahw44@FxGLoT5@vPzNeo7b/VJDRqBtW7IiGdVwIZ9EcmYWc1qCaHby0EyMOOU8r/pof8mZ//9c3tzuEiHDG5w26QBjZgXtetrWT1lErTL@Li9iaUsUoki5e9i6Q8bcbZu9KAnnXsrihSk1iMXMReCnLOa4VBFDmDe7nOWXv/HfiyEj0batLMKFFkQxdRbB4PfnFqAjXFAoM3cr0y7yOj765IV8ckVJeW1vyMjUaa54ksK1LX09W22FdXHCraAoHasSs57seg4o9dhF/H/n4C6FMpxL@C06hLJwCP6@j3C0mODwuuI7N3U/vSnlp1/9IO9clvLU5e83GRUytNOzUCnjmYgtEafZi2R1FFXNWkxWOdoFMffeiUOHOLBLg4ykLeI2O/6@x4XmiLjVmiELz8JZnNAzriveOgQEDhkLZFhjYFGFuxttLBRrPSIH9/O8WqZtW1Lw0wtBSm3lF/Lmra8ObDupHnMItxYRbtkBSVSCEl2tPFaLohRaXk1p2PY7KX9/yz8m4oePBN6WDQKkwjGnxYjFGwaeTkInhBuO4YW40z/5mZTn5MmTBzKIHz4hQFSDe0ULf0qTW3CDeRHwlgLomAJUDDATf62P/1PKj3vwDhnEjzilJmpDqLgI/9DZ40JOI9KCcyKrArnFrxj01w35wS35ofwJ398aMogfE29QTEiIfR/wSSgxJfjY0qieZXHAJRW7jJfPb29aUdtdiB/Rw7ZhgT4yzZo0LGQrwsdkRI5KfoGOACyw7XqZb@RHUj787OiQQfzQJeJDHpFpFPwDls6iQLqYIiDMGmjLTsBY8SHMqu6YVzzFBfnZpSEjdB@b6@rNZkkOkASvaAgAqkeJmP0kfG79Lt/DJPIr@dMNKdPf212IH6EZqNMqA1UU3AqKFlOBQwSrNZQ9N7itg5@@OXMNN3mMmN17F9/8PmQQP9wUcWQ/R2JQpndWuJz3Iif67jIV/AP18T3uAnN8Ixe6iNz0Qfxo8DQEHoBL4UZ4cIQ6Zx4mwGDRtyYKUIF3ea/rdFZv@Wle7wITakRJ0QVBNhlIm9MM14CBkRsWWA1qF29UP8hH/PxBbpiIHy1Aa85Ba7alAosqpt8YRO3GCTmtGUzI9JO8ChFXu3/syyB@qISM0CJMsijGbaF6mCBMDjhWQlTHEvWIOdv947EM@zKIH9k04Loi5FVkJucQJVbBs6IDvCLdWpHLVIeM5z/JTx@@pQ/iR4YGgOHIL9GbiX4N6ACQCSR74KOZEJE6bzImJf86/ww@tsnQqsdLYrw0gxQHuGoNEBYb1BmU8cjZgEYkDbPPHU5J@cgfnEMTP2ZCqUJwiGmacBgDGuBVoJPYJjSsLhQzxz7/uPWvvPru9/syOv9Q0Fom6IRmkWlUSsADD2kOn2wqIGUpTw4T5Lk338IkDyDomXwwZBA/xuOI6wvUqZZkYMwAK6fZwD8QSCX3nH31XXmaB3l9hv4xcrbu@GGoD/jB6l6gZ0W4JYMBULidW4GOgut3eQX3@A1AdhXo/nTIIH54vbojPmngbWGCtxmPFA6ap0SOunMB8KCMp/@YHku/Kx/Jk/KjIaPjx1SQoyxwbDIGd1FQitVI1/2SQUPFJscixDvAMaTsb8//La/u4kBDRucfE9wxKzc@pAvwVxu4nKHzBdIGrXrOfix/lVc//PKoNPKNFCNna@LHBBCnXbpLB1zIAhUZQzo1OOvkgB85rLaFh/94QaaTDLpnQ0bnH7pQnRUsLBagBsBNGAdNQjisXPFd2PfTL@FgrnvJ7naX1PM@7m4arAG7WOEygHzS@BEMh@wuI5NOxDH59ye/SfurlL9JeX4fxzTxA3G@IMdPhDBDMgQ@FiwhaSaSOGSfODFnX6WPajnvDQwZMkrP2ZlY4Z0IM@wCEIUWjALRTcgX3hhDqEO@RZy1F2fPw82uyGL2ZRA/QHlglxSr0A2acRWOOS8ReRxHEnlBBOdAfnqj62Fk7PMbP9XED4UrIyws8xwCtV8DyGHAN0FcY0O6niM8UMgP5JXnfo9Sfjx0l44fZnuSVfCnoiJBB7fSFWSvZJwSIUSd4tk91Z09xa8fHxmUn7EfE5zbgpoaDTTSvjnydVDeqJlawAUsw0cQCLV8Hx8ni/h2nMMQP3o@6op1k7dIbPBOox1jrvsHzBozkEEwQ35fwYVudLWcGzKIH1VR/eAiOAz81Df4afVQpwU1A7ZtgiDjFk7y4AKZ9kGeM8SPFIl7E4A85IqCZYaTGGgFeFoATgkuB6v1HPUYwS/1WQDQgU4N8SN7ZKZQQCYL8beDSGWOgjWMCHVa6HeeMl7vbDnqXyn9kEH8CBaZLGugV2Wk4WwEMzim9ThHo9dPE6Ja7PHDCc7FdPeb/HXI8J3DFKYRgF@jf3gLMjQR15cFNCBa3GoO81oTvpa@3n67bjDED@vXPFeRDBBkS9EjXqoGKLQAM3kD7Qom20dSnujnkWWT0fEjIuydL07U7hAJDh8U860GREM7sNoUeq78uX/6Uf@adocM4kdwCSTOLcD1gLRg1QwtTExPEekmI4uKNFfc5Sk@eZykzL91l44fGaATsrMwawQWkicjTcJZA8rj5DL/QVEfj16BCJ0clt2XQfzIC7RWK5wKSgT8GOB6pBbwdHhstR3ml7fr7I@/9JsM4keMSGd4LmsPeltD1QJCQLkR2SrSWWk6yHhz7RjQ@D92IX4sE9yrk9SyQJM5w9eXoIEfnsnLZyK8pp/udIZ6QfYTmSGC8BFQLolKzJkz/AxELrESKav/lgoR4FmAj@dvtQyO3Rsylp4q4Zz4FpV@q4WIBA9l5pxUBFZTUKyeZXaS8hNQh89edcukI6PaZ9jSBCjaC50ejlVIdgNcTDs4rIayxRLLKE33eo557/apfXXY3v5YoPMA9AcDYvUD/xd@Buag8nCgV/gCTt7N8gJE/8dbd9fLPBwyCB/NRvxWgotVhBvUV9kjAIsqSL@IYtCgptUoTaUyXZ8HZrGEDzXj45PGg3UoRFJ8vBpY2kWw27A4UKklTquM4/xy7Ub3@iGD8FHpCqAsYPYe@XUxqD/AHCpC2dHtXCAd62EbyLIllPEjK@4hg/CB4EVmWWBMFHENzkkuOQEZW2P1UxKd3tI9/j3dDTOK/k@HjE4/lkKXzGyhgFouxvQLWRT@EDnzGh4lgBCkUc8nktwnn5CTDRmEDz0jOhPSJEAAJaSfSE9BV@EaqAvLYumBM6jUiTXk5T16x6f7dyF8zCHx7h6aBAujgQEkGUmiMnAM/hJ5aulwKjPLOIn08PGf@zLmHvpwZO2XAhnIa7aEtvJiMPEmFguUnydL295jevp6jTktPx8yCB@IqX54lDsKeXvm4WENFKl01uiQuybPFtvfuIXiLW52C48WmyV8NMYLiqGNNnlQupygCuvgKUuYiSY1rPECCvWtlBcPhb4lfMxQiFCRfsoYLRXRh1oIaXzpMA1pqOMZLy9Xu364Quo8ZHT6UZCtAxsLsCgNjKuVmQ0cYtnkQAXg9ID137oQIgBbOjIOGZ1@VBwBlAxOspALVcRoMrDQXOGdxQePm66lKRy8/bse5p/9uyxbKZYcEsLCbosN@K5NCtICrVwV061yQx/yUuf7B/pwvXxpyB3OOzLIBlVMIaw1XS34JKpmZKxYGfu7P/@2K9951vPtL883GcQPN4MmlznjcQ4O4TzKbEN7LxalplnAfaeqcY5fHvPDP38FGV@cAxANGcQPFH4IcY8sknW1a9GeAjJFYDU4O3xcMfeLrgSU62DtgZXukEH8MBG2tRlQEzPcK4NFrN3DkkDzvOYTpgX4EV9@JUfr4UoGFRkyiB@oC4C/gT21BjtmAqjTwDawQoYbnuCmCT528tVqkh@kU/Ll1h5zvf0xwYS5pyPaRYO/wb1o4Nodh@S1@K2slMf6V3jK/SGD@AFiz55aw4VY3oLxNLp5JsGGTpO2os3TKJG/eS4f0NPPHNvXR@htXKT9AF2gToArLbxBWXxi42QGAICo5jz1dnLPUqhvP7tMIBsyiB/ZorhQnmUUjeMSoFQzoXh8VICYAseYrcR6hZundnrn89YmY@76AHEpZPZ4OJ5OdzFwcYAqbFWgd8DlwHXkhMuPz5JMfXp6k0H8ANUoLPIN6VsEuMOOU4WjTShFgGPgdQABxO0zdrRuLGzmyI/lHyeGjLziKdyAN04R6sdfoo4s7FBX4COuAbStoEbAU9zhfu9L5VsH8VJ6fgEd63nOoxLEESZW7pCRPSBpqUiTQMbR5s8fdxl/yIcfbDKIH2HJbPZyZEE2Vxr4l1t601TjHMBBVCKxl4TXLq29vpvvptu/bzKIHzO1lvA8oLN1UCL4tk0oSDMb0ZPT9JTgR4vtIosoJO8P5D9DRi9fcmRLmuhlECotM14Kkl1NFawy42zarqX69X0G87c8Nkp1r/pdYFa9EJgbfAyko6c98m24eYgFoFo6/zCngUI/d0d7DsY8ZEydFuLIIKHAdYsTxQp/iuzQTcuMf1igZ1ASxv6Lw7xwo4We@AGowQ0Mu54atrWlGfZLe4sZ/u@nGTWdCb0Uk@/e/5q9bfbrwpDR@UdBLT/RSVQ1ZGEebo5wJVcGECkWQzA9ZOz1wuMu3NQ8goKHDNvLBrb11nMATxNRwDjteTa4nEGSafw7QfLBPqF7/zA99Wv7Y4ZPTkkL1fozgRpLxDVSTBbuAvIK6ye2P/gHBuZNdq5tMjp@WDAo76G/MoPOFdRWQAFYQ7O3PSNqkC/W/LIwXD/tnalblzYZvXxhhqweZMEDa6g/cnzYtqAMg2vAzS0ZjvgGrOFBb9QRzb7ZZPT2adc8McgZ0J3kS0G5j3hRNFOwQFuLhCEEUf3HtRd8f@/VxTpkzD3PZTjmoqlJNeNqgOPqErxTc8w1gzakUldueXRtfUCzb/Z1SvxAvUeTIFrxXDAodvkie651Rsia3ptls0gg1FBknzkvj8qHYFMvhwziB5gw4jZCFbahLpwj3RblMXwXuQ@2AVFbfV3ekFdfw1sv9@JhO0fp@VbXdQazHoaEG0bvA5MC1l0AIiXSLqd4EiGbvCnvHvhHH7@YAOdmvw@1JQc34BrZkL7T@aYMoxsWVOLoE7aUZETVACPPmwziR02AH82ulne4CwhEXT8UEsApzxA5O@ZKeWnnanvNT7/skoYM4gfCfGbRB0yuSFSuu5dG3MLIDYexBT7m45bnfoVVwFC/vnTnyJjwreNbA7rD3s0M5q5r4JgQ/LskDUxhDV9Kzw3dOU49Rq3/zkG8BOJHa4AfxFwmDe19Fw4Nuk4be4bsIKg@Skq9c4JEd7M3DoaMzj/IEyZLdfptDgYEYwsWn8x6@9dxl1OX3y4rg@nlPsABd4efasV@BzCrWjg32M9W8zeEFMr9e6DHklz7g0MyiB8ICJTlE0yoDNs2GtWCm5HdYgI4JVBg1BIcA11aO1uf/MKyzm9joED8mMkjQTUcR9HAD2eQvSdgELRARIOntHle4@WpLBfPsKt0@@Acvf3R@jARv2VQ0ImIh6I@C5xWAL3yhEQ1o@Je9fGxQezvnethN2QQP8yy4OlxJoQ1Dn7BPxwnlRMnoMl4diCJQefklwCg26o3MNq@DOJHKwsyQkF1YRLPjSwNULVqDd4ywYHNbNfx3OdnVjg8Kq/OV4aMXr/0NpZb5zhJBFcSbpBBAxp8pnCAqshOIOPimWvy6WbaUe@HtN4lkJZHsjuOrzy7/si8wQOY/YIayLH7hbuQTH22yIv/XHuob2x36fjhK1tyQC@b@tAWP46hLfQ8cwbTmhpt/ivb1PTALsSPJc8cdkys0NnUWVo/PEoAuguKCtiK3gYZP3XcgJ//Dgz6YMiovYVCSjjjBibWxnE21BmQ9lzocj1Zdyj9HEvs4@zr8m55@XrI6Phhkd5dQo6a6KKV@wo1oZrUkaV@Yds@Tl2nN9ca@U/cJm11Q@j9j8TSjzVkz3MHed8tnWsn8LzU3OF20J8oDf8aMiLxw4Etc77AkgFOUkgDeh8GJRK8Pk7ML3A58dOtP@X3nzP7y06IhoyOH@wCL5w4w4zQAgGgVpB8wC0YIlcgLJ6Dc1xBxXFybbPJoxd/HjL02kMB/GRHUrtAkEeG9AZYXx3yRdHcHTB9dePVSqZK7wRvqxvRdG6JhySkIUQ8eLI28JTg2FjiGDn7XrD3OvtneekXuPlT9tnkx6POjsQPRHcFgYBSgICFwwstSmzcfmDpvuAcLjBeboPaKpYvHRKvj3iJvX5JnrUHqIrVk6d7AY416K2Go8Jq3AYJdnCY8yvNBmW@dGHI6PjBymDiCGde2JcOSPmQyw4dGxIkQ74ctPqufyML/39vs0voqxvsbRUk@koTasQxQrB40JFE@gJT@wX/KvpHpbjH/sml8w83GbGPPTQnDZylFdwgVCBPr719A/sPSDXg2oY6fe/Fv/IP1tlgMsd/t0NGH78kNtUJAJEjz0DW3SqwEPzIsdFWEcuK@qjDTcEP37u/xW3s/Q8qsbK9EB38ydeKqtYCOhSZPvgF@KZje72wZjh6f@V0@@312Me3BfCzmBkFCGf8lsVlK3AXlFAOjsPhzIR0Kl6TZf91hSU/y8Ifh4x1/IIkVugfUwD4xQXPVBaqUGxwmxncUuc49/HLrTE7uT3vbPVL7O3TmcMADq20AaguCfpYAnge8ksAJQSu29muI89nR8@MEX@7vPlH63jK1ngFfqSWmCCo3bWDyRaz54gKhVHHUzmK9WvS/rado/c/2BoHw2Y3Cv4UOUZeGqgHqFgHdy7LVPNWO/nQ@sfc@x9lJoZP5FIAIvilP9TP6As3ik2v0XdQcu1h7Mvo/Q/On@KEPBcc7GgN6i7HUXSYwKVaxAHnooAfv/eEe@Gf7x4@Piyj84@EX0iNnwTvWueTynKaq@aE3IcfgVVrn@6fX/7clfLcI3nmQIZZc7bFXaB5Pzdun8EaKBHh5uTJPnJmOWrTfy7c7eObXXkHgDRkED@KOWiIzY1Pn9eGmGFhmBNPVErvXWydMeSHc1s9NxM/lqoL@7jg1Rxn5wZm2zzoXFVFcVQA73GOeQ4iJirinRUEhgzf@@uklaQZaoEJl6g4OtGLyBEg2RvvOpNLPV/LKLl3mo2yzU9n4sekwUAXcDM8vc0CrFJxl4eVDFtBDjA48WxCfi2fjI6yfHplX6cdP8Dy4fC9jnKZQQZ@OvEI7AWjPJ5JHTcc@1X2dt2xF/sy@vpHATv2lW1StjlSA65PC/6u2MSZG/RRJjir@E3e1/sj/gPbpj6e4@QqcBbfYMzkAI0LewbBwL0ym8SRO2F9HLW2pJ8c9jHiR@HTUS4jXU@UxnWHxlpiUayjFjbIkzo8fnmyFmVDRtkfrXFsBIqAzMSGuimN099K/GBhY@ByfbT28qW8TvYw3zy6yahrn39ZvXlCkHILQ62NehOYg1lgLbMKh@M2vHfoLsQPZ6BOGAMpIBLMbOQkm012R5BUyLwmwuXEj9DonVt9jeS5PBXfGTKIHwW8UuDhEFQ5COcWC2o6zoEr9MxGACqT7Ry/rYR73j9H6uPbZDgNBwB4Tl1RGSPc0sxtTeacCSQkqsy64aNbvTP2sk8r92VM2zrMeo2FHZwZeDNnUMLe6pp4mMmvPfp@E/65cUhG739MDvgLBEW6XiMHiY18bE7RssvLUePC2P@lg@nxm38yfLdRYzIrl4r0RMNWK7t@sCjqFZQMGqA6k2klzTWUn@5sdsndUYeMlX9oHhnGBOYw3LiNCgQFDE7cUILGAfAN/GOnh/31W12v8uqQ0ce3bEk5j2Cfdb8Q0LmwB5s4HJtJAzTXn8Qz@fPp0cd9BeqwnYP4sZg@0@OwZEEZqyyMmSOKh95t67NCUBJyywt91Wo/cQ8ZxI/ATUTcBbWKxokgUbH/B3zMqMAKx491AvkVL77ve0qgUx98iW8@GTLW@QuSEooeTvbBvWYDnU6a2kUWZRE/EdbC2ud/fzvGtHd8yCB@ZM29NXaznWPnsBYu94KZeQ4hFRuJ1mjG7Vdk/b@vKwKXLpweMnr/NBq3PqmCocNdcBfdUGsaC5ZeFxA7S9cXz93e8Z7o2M45sfWDUu46XQrbceB0FqzUVUROC7BLa4lsN6NUDcsaL2e3tYsCujtkdPxwhet3cHilMlcmGsvSubJOhG25oKZn/J14urr4utCitrXPRPxICzcAA3wh2oSc3XNDS9BHaIaNs8iaptfql16xafGmV7dnNxmt50qDp5NNTwu8HiVA5IaBZkvbrdsPwAPV16U@hzpp1770MGQQP3Bh5jR2cLiCg@xUVlhTHN3OFrHcB46CM5P7W@mxn@cy8UN7z4Y6Q3xiT6lyYsLMZJQ2K9qCFgJP37@/w0WDL9wVdXQPVh4yOn4gt3CvcYIgwFXj1rRjTVNRiwBEGmevo1b/njXld1cOc5is1zkhvIjRmrmw0Wcnlr3Pmjkrj4bcSHedfnp9TJN25Cdq9Ndzx4@FG01L907D7VWwmUhQLdxTNJHdVTarBaEHQdcJVdyTF4cM4kdQSAaW/SMXZo7VoOJpyhzfoKoFCWHkoFgUj5C01650/uDswV1cXyHpW4Ea4D6zwiywaO7biaZvJ3Iakf3ayzm2LbDiz90hg/iRFB63NMXcyilU7qrgywSFoMo1g8rrirWDAzf78us/D@mU@OEywNJwUcJy/cOURHINBdjcU77hggnnQL@CyX0K//zg4ldstI05UO79jzhxise5R1n02mQHvXXcKAns1heAmfWHcuXFvgDyxZBB/FiZMHffoABOx6FY6ztn5csBE2fiSq/9oL85F/@ie6k8NmT09XULHGsNvxW44tl32OEQoBIB52jeeNhqzPePPVsBpC8rDBl9/YPtOFfZavW5Ozegkb3uiassqsxccV66jN87Fv/wVv8jEz8M0atYRUHEda5GqcCRn/ONnVEmcyQ7oQ8Wvx4c3ZWPhozOP9xUVqdStQB0NJRoLPwj@r4YM/du26G@g139Y8w9cut9OiSUhntBC6asWz2WgdentjGBnZTCPj/7dOrsHtdgORPf7kL88DO3RNjX0wGcx0Ru@HIpQC@A9Bx7EwRXE3flSYByhIDTl6jYI2Obv9sF6doh0A8toi4KCbZvLCrNYQb3uMW@Nq72o9weMqbO@eEBzXCkPvXV7L73ijznSdoRcxon4swTPvGHfPgZ20LvnJXbfK70/Y8ZxWiGUlnqgM1wh8TFviXMfbiZ0wul919dKbduyKtnT1zb@lLF9P4YQCf39ZG@nUieEGpnd/APN2cwokWvdlHA1Kv/gnv8Irc5cunrpz1JKwRNqkj@WnPeQFirGtR0YjtEmZ5v1ZgTXJc34Wgj35b@@gvSLuILdlk0t77YUtEJrCMpFpwsM/Pc12Dloz2mlpP35KFXV0rf/wjguAu7JNEXvk3EjDdzmU8HMgBoq6tYHO8Tgr6f@OzA10vvf3hcthC9Jk76PQcdtmW@XFT5ilDhuyRcxV/IjtPdN1fX8naTsa6PTWTYqF907C9okK4m3KByV8E5x0Q8Dc6/syM/4usF3IIfMvr81iK0EuvKkImF6wo8yo6oy7L@q2ZVIeQDeeFVX4Fn1L2/yejrY6ubwwagpixGwUqjq10zC/vU3dv6bO34TXlqEMz7y@AwJfe79FElHEJHMP3J8jWLwtVivvQVLHzGsdXLu9zasRuj@3k7B/HDkVIrFKdcYQWxKwCMwLeaHOcYC5fQgbHItz/w/YhZ7r5wvxzWKfHDcxVfcdIDd4Em3bT1cWdcI06QVpHNhEgDP3aY/t2@jNZrZHqWSZyGtd5O4msWOBHScX87AiSVvUwht8XCWZ7@7JQ8P2T0/ilZB5yKLQcU24HL3wtMCpEowBcLQoUaefQ/Lsh/zoE2fHhQI9d1/wPG9AoRMQcOwVkCRB8r6RmoOopxAR5D26pbx2VuwzDb@mklfqSEa1TNw1Q2TWacI3Ji0t9NCp4vtthDeHqO/dd/9vG0Ej@cmsJY6dUFzKVyA3Zh67S99V6R@G6NWvlwtMeHjM4/2BD7/3ivSPznzaaBH7Xvf8z/14tVBy9Pif@82bSdg/jxf79YdfDylPjPm02bjI4fh16sAq2cmGU7rC0L9TyxNEt8zeLYxbdfShwywsFrjXyJkFBqSZYtW3@snQ7/4RuRF69@Ls/fkv8P)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](http://www.php.net/) (>=5.4), <s>199</s> 197 bytes

(-2 bytes by more golfing)

```php
<?$s=strlen(file_get_contents($argv[1])).'';echo strtr([waning_crescent,waning_gibbous,new_moon,0,waxing_crescent,waxing_gibbous,full_moon,first_quarter,third_quarter][($s[0]+$s[3])%11-2],'_',' ');
```

To run it:

```
php -d error_reporting=0 -d short_open_tag=1 <filename> <image_path>
```

Example:

```
php -d error_reporting=0 -d short_open_tag=1 lunar_phase.php https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Moon_phase_6.svg/240px-Moon_phase_6.svg.png
```

**Notes:**

- The `-d error_reporting=0` option is used to not output notices/warnings.
- The `-d short_open_tag=1` is required to allow short tags.
- If you are using a `https` URL like the example above, [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) should also be enabled.

---

## How?

Gets file size (bytes) and creates a unique number for it by this formula:

`((<first_bytes_digit> + <fourth_bytes_digit>) % 11) - 2`

This formula generates numbers from 0 to 8 with only a 3 missing.

```
┌─────────────────┬───────┬─────────┬─────┬────────────────────────┐
│      Phase      │ Bytes │ 1st+4th │ %11 │ -2 (position in array) │
├─────────────────┼───────┼─────────┼─────┼────────────────────────┤
│ new moon        │  3451 │ 3+1=4   │   4 │                      2 │
│ waxing crescent │  6430 │ 6+0=6   │   6 │                      4 │
│ first quarter   │  5144 │ 5+4=9   │   9 │                      7 │
│ waxing gibbous  │  7070 │ 7+0=7   │   7 │                      5 │
│ full moon       │  5283 │ 5+3=8   │   8 │                      6 │
│ waning gibbous  │  7067 │ 7+7=14  │   3 │                      1 │
│ third quarter   │  4976 │ 4+6=10  │  10 │                      8 │
│ waning crescent │  6337 │ 6+7=13  │   2 │                      0 │
└─────────────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────┴────────────────────────┘
```

---

## Previous approaches:

#### [PHP](http://www.php.net/) (>=5.4), 251 bytes

```php
<?foreach([4,8,16,20]as$w){$a+=imagecolorat(imagecreatefrompng($argv[1]),$w*10,120)>1e7;$a&&$w<5?$b=-2:0;}$x=explode('_','full moon_waning gibbous_third quarter_waning crescent_new moon_waxing crescent_first quarter_waxing gibbous');echo$x[$a*++$b+4];
```

To run it:

```
php -d error_reporting=0 -d short_open_tag=1 <filename> <image_path>
```

Example:

```
php -d error_reporting=0 -d short_open_tag=1 lunar_phase.php https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Moon_phase_6.svg/240px-Moon_phase_6.svg.png
```

**Notes:**

- The `-d error_reporting=0` option is used to not output notices/warnings.
- The `-d short_open_tag=1` is required to allow short tags.
- PHP must have [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and it should be enabled.
- If you are using a `https` URL like the example above, [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) should also be enabled.

---

#### How?

Checks for the color of 4 pixels in the image at `40,120`, `80,120`, `160,120` and `200,120` and decides on the moon phase from those colors.